# Get the case of a character in python

Tags: python, char

Is there a property of characters that returns the case? Like maybe `char.case()`? I need this to get rid of some repetitive code that's bothering me.

Comment: The answer to repetitive code is to define your own function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions `isupper()` and `islower ()` are what you need

```
>>> 'a'.isupper()
False
>>> 'A'.isupper()
True
>>> 'b'.islower()
True
>>> 'B'.islower()
False
```

Comment: Okay, I guess there isn't a `.case()` function. I know of the functions you mentioned, it's just that I wanted to get rid of some repetitive code where I had `if str.upper()` followed by `elif str.lower()`. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Barghav Rao I had messed up some formatting and accidentally pressed the enter button. It should be fixed now.

Comment: @PolarBearITS You are welcome, Your `elif` can be `else` only, as if `str.upper()` is false, then the other (`str.lower()`)will be correct

Comment: @BhargavRao not necessarily, for example `'1'.isupper()` and `'1'.islower()` are both `False`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks ... But better if you had tagged the OP so he would have learnt this

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) and [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower)

```
>>> 'a'.isupper()
False
>>> 'a'.islower()
True

>>> 'A'.isupper()
True
>>> 'A'.islower()
False
```